# using the spread operator in react setState on array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

I have an array of objects (language codes and names) that I am trying to spread into another array in local state in a react component. The structure of the array I am trying to spread is like this:

```
let langs = [
  {code: "af", name: "Afrikaans"},
  {code: "sq", name: "Albanian"}
]
```

I am trying something simply like this:

```
this.setState({
  languages: [...langs]
}, 
  console.log(this.state.languages);
);
```

When I try to console.log languages in the callback from setState the array is empty. What am doing wrong here?

Comment: setState is an async action. Use the console.log() in the [setState callback](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate), or in render();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setState` is async, and you need to invoke the function in the callback.

```
this.setState({
  languages: [...langs]
}, () => console.log(this.state.languages)
);
```

Comment: Ahhhhh I feel so stupid now, thanks Stanley and Jamiec!

Answer (score 2):

The second parameter is a callback - you're executing `console.log` immediately and passing its result as the callback. Change you code to this:

```
this.setState({
    languages: [...langs]
  }, 
  () => console.log(this.state.languages);
);
```